# Unable to pass an argument to a function

Tags: bash, function, arguments

For my homework,  I need to have a function in my code to earn extra credit.  I have a script that takes the second argument and makes a folder from what is passed.  The code works with the argument outside the function.  However,  when I put the code in the function,  I'm unable to pass it the argument inside the function.

This is my function.  I've placed it at the top of the .sh file.

```
create_folders() {
echo "$2"

if [[ ! -d "$2" ]]; then

    echo "Making $2 Base Folder."
    mkdir "$2"

    else echo "$2 directory had already been created."

fi
}
```

Further down the code, I have

```
create_folders "$2"
```

I'm not able to figure out why it won't pass the argument.

Comment: you described a problem, but you did not ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing one argument, so in the function, it will be `$1`, not `$2`. `$2` is the second argument, as in

```
create_folders first second
```

Comment: Thank you,  that was it.  I'll accept your answer when it lets me.